# How to connect multiple Nginx containers on different networks on the same host together?

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile

There are 13 microservices with dedicated dockerized PHP, Nginx, and MySQL on the same host. The microservice `MS1` needs to make an HTTP request to microservice `MS2`. So the Nginx of `MS1` needs to see the Nginx of `MS2`. I would like to know whether it is possible to do such a thing.

Here is an example of `sale-service` and `product-service` docker-compose files.

```yaml
version: '3'
networks:
  sale_network:
    driver: bridge

services:
  sale_php:
    build:
      context: ${SALE_DIRECTORY}
      dockerfile: php8.1.Dockerfile
    container_name: "sale_php"
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    networks:
      - sale_network
    volumes:
      - ${SALE_DIRECTORY}:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "${SALE_PHP_PORT}:9000"
  sale_nginx:
    build:
      context: ${SALE_DIRECTORY}
      dockerfile: nginx.Dockerfile
    container_name: sale_nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "${SALE_NGINX_PORT}:80"
    networks:
      - sale_network
    volumes:
      - ${SALE_DIRECTORY}:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - sale_php
  sale_mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.0
    container_name: sale_mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "${SALE_MYSQL_PORT}:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: ${SALE_MYSQL_USERNAME}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${SALE_MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${SALE_MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      SERVICE_TAGS: sale
    networks:
      - sale_network

volumes:
  mysqldata:
    driver: local
```

and product service

```yaml
version: '3'
networks:
  product_network:
    driver: bridge

services:
  product_php:
    build:
      context: ${PRODUCT_DIRECTORY}
      dockerfile: php8.1.Dockerfile
    container_name: "product_php"
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    networks:
      - product_network
    volumes:
      - ${PRODUCT_DIRECTORY}:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "${PRODUCT_PHP_PORT}:9000"
  product_nginx:
    build:
      context: ${PRODUCT_DIRECTORY}
      dockerfile: nginx.Dockerfile         
    container_name: product_nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "${PRODUCT_NGINX_PORT}:80"
    networks:
      - product_network      
    volumes:
      - ${PRODUCT_DIRECTORY}:/var/www/html      
    depends_on:
      - product_php
  product_mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.0
    container_name: product_mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "${PRODUCT_MYSQL_PORT}:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: ${PRODUCT_MYSQL_USERNAME}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${PRODUCT_MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${PRODUCT_MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      SERVICE_TAGS: product
    networks:
      - product_network
    
volumes:
  mysqldata:
    driver: local
```

Comment: The two containers need to be on the same Compose network.  The linked question describes how to import one Compose file's network into the other; either have the files share a `default` network, or explicitly put the client and server on to the same network.

Comment: @DavidMaze can they be connected using the local IP address?

Comment: In principle you could connect by calling out to the host system, provided the other service publishes `ports:`, yes.  Note that the local IP address won't be fixed (unless `host.docker.internal` works).